# Javascript Adding checked values w/o <form>

Tags: javascript

This is what I have come up so far https://jsfiddle.net/u30jdmna/ . I want to add the values of the textbox when the checkbox is checked without using `form` and when I press clear, I want to put `0` in all the textbox.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/01azkytj/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I Understand Your Question Right This Must Be Your Solution

[sample Code](https://jsfiddle.net/01azkytj/)

```
function zeTotal(){
    res.value=0;
    if (ck1.checked == true){
        res.value = parseInt(res.value)+parseInt(nm1.value);
    } 
    if (ck2.checked == true){
        res.value = parseInt(res.value)+parseInt(nm2.value);
    } 
    if (ck3.checked == true){
        res.value = parseInt(res.value)+parseInt(nm3.value);
    } 
    if (ck4.checked == true){
        res.value = parseInt(res.value)+parseInt(nm4.value);
    } 
    if (ck5.checked == true){
        res.value = parseInt(res.value)+parseInt(nm5.value);
    } 
}
```